# May I place a towel on the food that's on the platta on Shabbos?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, melacha-creative-work, cooking-bishul

This is a hatmana (insulation) question. I want to know if there is an issue with putting food on the platta on Shabbos day and then putting a thick towel ontop of that food in order for the food to heat up faster and get hotter?

Answer (score 1):

You have three problems here:

1. *Hatmanah* on Shabbat itself
2. *Mosif hevel* -- adding heat
3. *Hatmanah* while it's on the *plata* (if that's what you're asking about)

All three of those issues make it *assur* (forbidden). [Shmirat Shabbat C'hilchata 1:65].

However, you can get around problems #1 and #3, as illustrated in the next paragraph.

*Hatmanah* is only a problem if you cover the entire pot. However, if your cover does not touch the entire thing, it's OK to do even *lechatchila* (initially) and while it's on the *plata*. It seems though that you'll have to use something that does not add heat.

*Mosif hevel* seems to be a problem even when it is fully cooked (see http://vbm-torah.org/archive/cookshabbat/22cookshabbat.htm, quoting Rav Auerbach).

[CYLOR](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/594/5151) before acting on advice given in this answer.

Comment: About covering the entire pot... I wonder if there are a bunch of dishes on the platta and I drape a towel over all of them but leave one of them slightly uncovered, would that help with the rest of them in taking care of issue's #1 and #3?

Comment: If you drape the towel over all of them, per force it is not touching the entire body of any pot.

Comment: Wouldn't that depend on why not having the whole pot covered would be OK? If it's a demonstration that you are not concerned with insulating the pot (I vaguely remember this being the position of a Rishon) then maybe in this case it would not help since it's clear that I'm draping the towel for insulation purposes? Just thinking here...

Comment: isn't moisif hevel only a problem when not yet fully cooked?

Comment: @hazoriz "actual hatmana with a davar she-mosif hevel, and one may not be lenient even about that which is fully cooked. " -- http://vbm-torah.org/archive/cookshabbat/22cookshabbat.htm, quoting Rav Auerbach.